Partially uncover TikZ figure in OpTeX slides
Is there a way to replicate the behavior of Beamer's \pause command in TikZ figures with OpTeX?
In Beamer I can do the following:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (5,-5) circle[radius=2];
    \pause
    \draw (10,-5) circle[radius=2];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

and get this result:

This approach does not work with OpTeX, as the \pg+ macro does not work inside the TikZ environment.
I was able to somehow replicate the behavior using the remember picture and overlay TikZ options. This approach, however, does not behave exactly the same and is less convenient.
\useOpTeX
\slides
\load[tikz]

\slideshow

\tikzpicture[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (5,-5) circle[radius=2];
\endtikzpicture

\pg+

\tikzpicture[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (10,-5) circle[radius=2];
\endtikzpicture

\bye

result:


This is not really an answer to your question, but there are several different approaches to this situation.
If the graphics you want to draw are as simple as about in your example, can probably use direct PDF syntax and the pdf related primitives (\pdfliteral, \pdfsetmatrix, \pdfsave, \pdfrestore,  etc.), you can read about this syntax in the graphics section of the pdf specification manual, and about the primitives in pdfTeX's manual.
If you want to see some examples,  the author of OpTeX wrote some answers in this forum using this method, for example [1], [2] and [3]. In addition, OpTeX provides some macros to simplify things, if this is the approach you will eventually take, I would recommend reading sections 1.6 and 2.29, in particular about the \_circle and \puttext macros in this case.
For example, the example in the question can be produced with the following
\useOpTeX

\def\circle{\vbox to 4cm{\vss\hbox to 4cm{\hss
    \pdfliteral { q \_circle{\_bp{4cm}}{\_bp{4cm}} S Q }%
    \hss}\vss}}

\slides
\dimen0=\dimexpr-.5\vsize-2cm+\voffset
\slideshow

\puttext \dimexpr.33\hsize-2cm-\hoffset \dimen0 \circle

\pg+

\puttext \dimexpr.66\hsize-2cm+\hoffset \dimen0 \circle

\bye

Another options is to produce the image by any means you want,
not necessarily with OpTeX, or even TeX, you can compile the tikz
code separately, or use Inkscape or MetaPost, then insert the image at the position you desire with the \putpic macro (the description of \directoutput can be found here)
% file: circle.tex
\useOpTeX

\directoutput\vbox to 4cm{\vss\hbox to 4cm{\hss
    \pdfliteral { q \_circle{\_bp{4cm}}{\_bp{4cm}} S Q }%
    \hss}\vss}

\bye

\useOpTeX

\slides
\dimen0=\dimexpr-.5\vsize-2cm+\voffset
\slideshow

\putpic \dimexpr.33\hsize-2cm-\hoffset \dimen0 0cm 0cm {circle.pdf}

\pg+

\putpic \dimexpr.66\hsize-2cm+\hoffset \dimen0 0cm 0cm {circle.pdf}

\bye


I'm not that familiar with luamplib, but maybe it collaborates better with \pg+ than tikz, so it is another thing to consider.
